# Google sheets return Values only if exists

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this Google sheets

[image]

In column K, I only want to return values if they are pre-existing in Column E,F, Etc..

How can I do this knowing that I will add months 2023-02, 2023-3, etc?

Here's my example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FMBkmMKJuIn0qtxDzvaWG2x5IpcR92X4-G9b8DUd9Z4/edit#gid=0

Comment: Question is not so clear. You may try `IF()` like `=IF(E4<>"",J4+E4/$C$1,"")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array formula.

In I4 you can put

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(C$3:F$3), H4:L4+C4:F4/$C$1, ""))
```

and drag down

And enable iterative calculation as the formula depends on its earlier results (ok to limit to 1 iteration I think)